# Not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pip

```
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am trying to use ipython in a Windows cmd line.  I get the same error when I use `pip install Jupyter`

I have tried adding Python36 and Python36/Scripts directories to the Path variables, but the result is the same.

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

is the Python version and I am on a Windows 10, 64 bit machine.  HELP!

Comment: did you try to use the anacoda shell, it should setup the environment

Comment: if you added the scripts directory then just using "activate.bat" prior to pip should do it